# How to concatenate multiple video files with a single audio file using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

Here is how i concatenate mp4 files :

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -i vid3.mp4 -filter_complex [0][1][2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -r 30 output_vid.mp4
```

But i am unable to figure out to add a audio file as background music to the whole concatenated video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the audio as a typical input and use the [`-map` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) to select it:

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -i vid3.mp4 -i audio -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" -map 3:a -c:v libx264 -preset fast -r 30 -shortest output_vid.mp4
```

If the audio file is AAC, then add the `-c:a copy` output option to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) it instead of re-encoding it.